# How should messages (not exceptions) be passed from the Model/Business Object layer to the UI?

Tags: .net, events, mvvm, message

Using VB.net 4.0

I have a Winforms application that is loosely based on MVVM.  I'm looking for an easy way for any layer (even those that the UI has no reference to) to pass messages back to the UI for display to the user.

I have accomplished this in the past by creating a "Communicator" class in a "Common" assembly that every other assembly would reference.

```
Public Class Communicator

Public Shared Sub NotifyUser(Message as string)
    RaiseEvent SendMessage(Message)
End Sub

Public Shared Event SendMessage(MessageToSend as string)

End Class
```

The UI would subscribe to the SendMessage event at program startup.  Any class wanting to pass a message to the user would simply call the Shared NotifyUser method and the Communicator class would relay the given message to the UI through the SendMessage event.

The upside to this method is that it is trivial to implement and super easy to use from anywhere in your code.

I suppose the downside to this is that calls to NotifyUser are spread throughout your code, making many classes dependent on the Communicator class and its shared method.  For some reason, it just feels wrong.

So, my question is, what are some typical ways to achieve the same effect without a significant increase in complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly events are fine (with the downsides you pointed out). Another option is the [Mediator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx#_self1), which is more or less what it sounds like you've implemented, just without events.

Comment: Can you give an example of using events in a different manner than what I posted?  In theory I know you could fire an event directly on any class that wanted to send a message, but that means wiring up every class that wants to do so as it is created.  I'm curious as to other solutions/examples.

Comment: I would encourage you to not use events actually. They can lead to tight coupling and, if not implemented correctly, memory leaks. Instead use a message based approach, where objects register to be notified based on a message. This is one implementation that comes to mind. It's for WPF, but should work for you with minimal or no changes. http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/